# Comparing multiple lm results created in ggplot2

Tags: r, regression, lm, ggplot2

I have the following example plot:
[image]

Created via:

```
test_data<-mpg
test_data$multi<-rep(c("A","B","C"))
p <- ggplot(test_data, aes(displ, cty,color=multi)) + geom_point()+ stat_smooth(method = "lm", fill = NA)
p + facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl))
```

My question is:

I just want to compare the created `lm` models to see if they are significantly different from one another. For example, I would like to compare the green line from the first column & first row to the pink line from column 2 * row 2 (5,f).

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) 
for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Cross Validated!

I'll start with that I'm not 100% certain I understand the question. It may be that you are going about this in reverse. I would suggest you start out with fitting your data to your model (`lm`) and then using graphical methods to explore your fits. You can do this with ggplot.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to extract the information about the fits from `ggplot`. However, if you do the `lm` regression outside of `ggplot` you will get the same information.

Also, I notice that you did not specify a formula in `geom_smooth`, so I think it will default to `y~x`. If this is what you want, then perhaps you would be best to start out with a model such as

```
fit = lm(Yvals ~ Xvals + ColorVals + Xvals:ColorVals, data=all_sum)
```

I would suggest exploring the examples in the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html). [This blog post](https://sejohnston.com/2012/08/09/a-quick-and-easy-function-to-plot-lm-results-in-r/) gives a nice function you can use to plot the results of a given fit with many useful annotations. Also, [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381158/getting-equation-for-lm-ggplot-geom-smooth-with-multiple-levels) sounds a bit similar to yours and does have an accepted answer.

I hope this helps!